# Angular 6 : How do I set production and development base url

Tags: angular

New to angular I want to set different base url for production and development. I want to dynamically set it so that to reduce the pain of hard-coding in index.html while switching between production and development

```html
<!-- Production url will be as below-->

<base url="/prod/" />

<!-- Development url will be as below-->

<base url="/dev/" />
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use `environments.ts , environment.prod.ts` files at build(dev) time you will got 
environments.ts and production time you will be using environment.prod.ts

and you can setup your own configuration ⚙

Development

```
export const environment = {
  production: false , 
  url : '127.0.0.1:4200/api'
};
```

Production

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  url : 'production.com/api'
};
```

app.component

```
import { environment } from "../environments/environment";

export class AppComponent {

  ngOnInit() {  
    console.log(environment.url);
  }
}
```

the console output will be `127.0.0.1:4200/api` if you run `ng s` and `production.com/api` in case you run `ng s --prod`

When you build for production `ng build --prod` the environment.ts will be the content of `environment.prod.ts`

[Becoming an Angular Environmentalist](https://blog.angularindepth.com/becoming-an-angular-environmentalist-45a48f7c20d8)

Answer (score 1):

You can change the production config in angular.json file under

> architect>>build>>configurations>>production

You have to add the production baseHref, such as the below :

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For delevopment you can set this in environment.ts file. Like that

```
export const environment = {
  production: false,
  baseUrl: 'http://test.net/api'  
};
```

and for production in environment.prod.ts

```
export const environment = {
  production: true,
  baseUrl: 'https://prod.net/api'
};
```

Then you should use url in your services like that

```
@Injectable()
export class DataService {  

  baseUrl = environment.baseUrl;

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getData(id: number) {
    let url = this.baseUrl + '/data/1';
    return this.httpClient.get<JSON>(url);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to have at least two typescript files in your angular project.
  environment.ts and environment.prod.ts.
For development you have to use the simple ng serve and for production you have to build and specify that you need the url from production to be used.

To do that use: "ng build --prod."

An article about that can be found [here](https://medium.com/@balramchavan/separating-production-and-development-http-urls-using-environment-ts-file-in-angular-4c2dd0c5a8b0) .