# baseApiUrl Issue in Angular JS Application

Tags: angularjs

I want to set a `baseApiUrl` inside `AngularJS` application's service class

```
export class EmployeesService {
  baseApiUrl: string = environment.baseApiUrl;
  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
  getAllEmployees(){
    this.http.get(this.baseApiUrl + '/api/employees');
  }
}
```

**But gives the below error. How to solve that?**

`Property 'baseApiUrl' does not exist on type '{}'.ts(2339)`

Comment: I suppose it is not AngularJS (a.k.a Angular version 1) but [tags:angular] (versions 2 and above).

Comment: Did you research on Stackoverflow? Found: [Angular 6 : How do I set production and development base url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55190517/angular-6-how-do-i-set-production-and-development-base-url)